# New colony with plausible lack of transportation infrastructures

Tags: technology, technological-development

I'm designing a roleplaying game set in a colony in a distant star. I'm no scientific expert and I don't want the setting to be hard sci-fi, however, I do want it to be credible.

What plausible reasons could there be for a colony on an alien planet to lack transport infrastructures but still have access to other technologies working to ensure survival on that planet, assuming a tech level that would enable us to set up a colony on a planet light-years away?

Here are a few constraints:

- Humanity reached the planet on an embryo-ship.
- The A.I. androids started building the new colony.
- Humanity was raised and educated by A.I. androids.
- Of the initial 50,000 embryos, only 10,000 were raised by the A.I. for unknown reasons.
- The first humans shut down the A.I. androids (there are a few rogue ones).
- These 10,000 humans are now trying to get the half-finished colony under way to prepare it for the second wave: the remaining 40,000 embryos.
- Transportation between settlements must be sparse.
- There must be different settlements around the main settlement (no more than 2-3 days journey), much like the Old West.

All these ideas are subject to change if not feasible or plausible. Again, this will not be hard sci-fi, more like space fantasy.

Comment: Because it's new? A newly established colony will very naturally lack transport infrastructure. Building roads, railways, ports, airports etc. does take time.

Comment: When you say, "only 10,000 were raised by the A.I. for unknown reasons", do you secretly know the reasons? I ask because an answer might be that the robots inexplicably failed to build the transportation system, for the same reason they failed to raise all the humans (whatever that reason is).

Comment: No, I don't know the reasons. It may be the case that no one will ever know the reasons. I'd like to leave some blank areas so the players can explore and find out during the game. However, given that it is plausible that, for some reason, the A.I. did not build a transportation system, what reason could there be for the humans not to build a transportation system? Lack of resources? I would like the Colony to be as advanced as anything existing today on Earth if not somewhat more advanced.

Comment: When you say "no transportation", do you mean "no transportation back to Earth" or do you mean "no cars, no trains, everything has to be done on foot"? And would carts be okay? What about bicycles or cross-country skies?

Comment: Everything has to be done on foot. At the very least, transportation should severely impaired with very limited access to land transport. I want the characters to walk around on foot more often than not.

Here's the gist of it: characters will be transporting cargo and stuff, so bicycles should not be a thing. Again, it doesn't have to be realistic, but plausible.

Comment: You are the writer. You should know the reason behind things, even if you never tell the readers. You need to keep the story consistent.

Comment: Why are there multiple settlements and what is their positioning relative to (the remains of) the ship? Who has custody of the ship, and is it sufficiently intact that it can sustain the embryos and provide for their development? If the reason for dispersal is that different groups of people don't get on very well with each other it sounds more like current-day America rather than the Old West.

Comment: Where is the embroyo-ship now? Did it land, or was it dismantled and the parts landed as colony resources? Is it still in orbit, and how expensive is transport to and from the orbiting ship? Or did it leave on its mission to establish further colonies? These are all quite different colony mega-environments.

Answer (score 16):

**New Colony**

Spaceship have limited cargo carrying capacity. Any vehicles sent would be few in number and allocated for set tasks. People would have to walk everywhere until the mining, smelting and manufacturing has enough surplus material to build transportation.

Many many other projects would be higher priority than transportation. Quite possibly horses could be sent because they can be bred thus not require the materials. Horses can be used for farming, transportation as well as eaten.

Answer (score 11):

**AI androids *were* the transportation**

For a sophisticated civilization capable of interstellar travel and colonization, there was no point in creating vehicles dedicated to human operation. While modern humans use "cars", "trucks" and "helicopters", this futuristic civilization uses multipurpose robots, capable of performing transportation, and much more. Maybe not quite on a level of "Transformers", but you should get the idea.

When all androids were shut down, that effectively robbed the colony of all methods of transportation. Single point of failure, some say, but this is how the story goes.

[image]

Comment: Watching the development of driverless (and steering wheeless) cars, this is definitely could happen. Also gives you narrative flexibility as to how much of the vehicle fleet is reliant on faulty AI.

Answer (score 9):

**Microbial corrosion.**

[image: microbial corrosion]

https://c1sinc.com/blog/mic-microbiologically-influenced-corrosion-fire-sprinkler-pipes

This is a wet planet.  And the microbes there like metal.  Microbes on earth like metal too but on this planet the microbes will add oxygen to pretty much any metal.  You can have electronics if you keep them sealed and dessicated.  But transportation tech as developed on earth is exposed to the elements and once the microbes get in, they eat, and eat.

The starships they landed in are heaps of oxides.  The vehicles your colonists brought are also useless.  Engines with metal parts to contain high temperatures or resist high stresses are prime fodder for the microbes.  Metal firearms are gone.

Wood can be used and your colonists have wood frame dirigibles.  Wooden bikes are out there, using fiber chains.   They are working on ceramic engines but it is slow going when the casting vessels keep oxidizing away.

Comment: I like this. A few points though:
- Would the planet have a higher content of oxygen than Earth?
- Would it rain more, being a wet planet?
- How would Humans live on this planet? What type of buildings, etc.?

Comment: @HugoB - microbial corrosion definitely happens on earth; it is a big problem.  You do not need to change much on your planet.  I envision the Pacific Northwest - a humid, forested planet.   Maybe there are more nutrients in the rain / fog than on Earth and if you want to know why ask another question.  Humans would live in houses not made of metal so no mobile homes.   Wood would be fine and there is plenty.  They might need to use stone tools to cut the wood.

Answer (score 5):

Local transport infrastructure will reflect the size of the local population, its geographic distribution and technology.

1. Population density and location. The population of the planet will initially be concentrated around the main landing area. Outlying settlements will probably be small and not to far from the 'spaceport' simply because unless some essential resource is located far away there's no real reason for them to be anywhere else. If you do have essential towns built elsewhere they will tend to follow the same pattern, one local big center surrounded by smaller townships within easy transport distance.
2. Resources will be allocated to key infrastructure first- hospitals, schools, essential industries etc. so big modern transport infrastructure waits till there is a population that both needs it and can pay for it.
3. Transport vehicles sent to the planet or built there will designed to cope with local conditions. So for example with no road/highway network you will have heavy duty off road vehicles operating on dirt tracks. No airports VTOL aircraft.  No railways - boats/barges

Also look at the history of the European expansion. When horses were the dominant form of transport small country towns tended to be about half a days cart ride from each other. When railways came along all the little towns disappeared and consolidated around trains stops because the economic justification for their existence disappeared. Then along came cars and and populations concentrated again with railway towns disappearing/shrinking and big rural centers growing a few hours car ride apart.

Answer (score 4):

I like Thome's answer, but here is another one:

**Power Systems and Fuel**

Right now, most transportation systems run by burning hydrocarbons. Others like direct electrical power (mostly trains), batteries (cars and bikes) and wind (recreational craft) are much less common. To get gasoline, diesel, and kerosene, there have to be fossil fuels, drill rigs, and refineries. High startup costs.

The alternative might be biofuels, but that competes with other uses of agriculture. Or water electrolysis to create hydrogen. Explosive and difficult to handle. High-capacity batteries are quite difficult to produce and they tend to have a limited lifetime.

So assume that they brought a number of vehicles with them, complete with spare part kits and initial fuel stocks, but only a very limited fuel production capacity. Solar power is used in some specialized roles, but they can't power a truck, jeep, or tractor. Perhaps the auxiliary motor of a sailboat. Or flimsy drones.

Month by month, the colony administration must allocate fuel to farming, construction, emergency services, and other uses. those "other uses" don't get much unless the geologists make a *real* good case for some prospecting run, or the like.

Answer (score 2):

The colony is small, and everything is at short distance, around the spaceport through which all communication [with other planets, as there's nobody else on *this* planet] happens.

Why would a transport infrastructure be needed, if the only place you might one something/someone is already the one we are on?

Answer (score 2):

### Quarantine Protocols

The settlements have been designed to start up independently with minimal interaction, so that any biological threat affecting one is not spread to the others. This made transportation infrastructure unnecessary until a certain point in development and resilience would be reached.

Unfortunately, that point was not reached according to the A.I. When humans decided to venture out and travel to the other settlements against the directions of the A.I., it sent out bands of androids to enforce quarantine protocols, by tracking down and capturing or killing offenders. These tracker androids operate independently and thus survived the shutdown of the main A.I.

Travelers between settlements risk attack by the androids at any time. Those caught relatively close to their origin city report having their vehicles, weapons, supplies and communications gear taken before being turned back. Those caught deeper in the wilds never return. It is unknown whether they are captured or killed outright.

Attempts at building any transportation infrastructure have failed due to sabotage and attacks on workers and supply trains.

Despite all this, people travel. The successful ones advise to travel light and on foot to evade detection. It may take days instead of hours, but the chances of arriving safely are much higher.

All of this should support the Old West vibe you're going for, though I wouldn't go as far as to call the independent androids "inde-ans". People on foot have some freedom of movement, but transporting cargo becomes a real tense affair. Finding out where the androids are based and what happens to captured humans is an option if you want the transportation issue to be resolved at some point.

Answer (score 2):

### The androids did not create any transportation infrastructure

They androids were supposed to build roads, rails and vehicles. But you already established that they were everything but reliable. So the transportation infrastructure could be yet another thing they were supposed to take care of but didn't. The new colony already starting 80% understaffed. And then they had to deal with a rogue AI crisis and the subsequent challenge to continue their struggle for survival without the android servants they expected to help them. There were too many other concerns which had higher priority than correcting that mistake.

When vehicles were delivered instead of built on site, then it's also possible that most transportation vehicles were destroyed during the AI uprising.

Infrastructure is always an investment into the future. When you are fighting for survival, then other concerns are often more pressing. That road network between your farms, granaries and canteens might surely enhance the efficiency of your food supply, but it's of no use when you starve to death while you build it.

Answer (score 2):

### Change of Plans

The AI planned for conditions that never came to pass, because the humans took things in a different direction.

Maybe the AI was planning on a hyper-dense arcology, where all 50k humans in the initial colony would live in a single building or small group of buildings. Transportation would be mostly by elevators and sky-bridges.

The Human rebellion that turned off the AI changes everything. Now, the arcology won't work because [reasons]. Humans return to a more traditional kind of life, with a central urban core surrounding by agricultural communities.

There are lots of [reasons] why the arcology doesn't work without AI. I would probably pick food, since it's so fundamental. The hydroponics / waste recycling / microbiomes required for arcology food production are just too hard without the AI, so the whole plan has to change with the end of the AI era.

Answer (score 2):

[The city of Norilsk in Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norilsk) might be what you think of.

> The city is served by Alykel Airport and Valek Airport. There is a freight-only railway, the Norilsk railway between Norilsk and the port of Dudinka. There is a road network around Norilsk (such as the A-382 which links to Dudinka and Norilsk Alykel Airport), **but no road or railway to the rest of Russia**. In essence, Norilsk and Dudinka function like an island. Freight transport is by boat on the Arctic Ocean or on the Yenisei River.

Reason:

> Despite being located inside the Arctic Circle, Norilsk has a **subarctic climate** (Köppen climate classification Dfc) with **very long, severely cold winters and very short, mild summers**. **It is covered with snow for about 250–270 days a year**, with **snow storms for about 110–130 days**.

So while they can move inside the city, moving outside is mostly a no-no (besides airplane).

Answer (score 1):

**Lack of suitable raw materials**

Lack of raw materials on the planet to construct and maintain such an infrastructure.

This idea comes to me from Robert Heinlein's "Farmer in the Sky", where a colony is severely constrained by a lack of suitable building materials on what was a lifeless world. There were no trees from which to harvest lumber and no extractable metal from the crust. Buildings were hewn out of rock.

The only metal-based products available were what was brought from Earth.

What little mechanical transportation that was available was rationed among the colonists, so while there were "roads", there was little in the way of traffic to make them more than just marked areas of rock.

Answer (score 1):

Disassembling a colony ship for parts once it reaches its final destination is basically a sci fi trope at this point happening across the entire genre, from TV shows like Star Trek to video games like Stellaris. Split your embyros up across multiple ships and have each settlement be the results of the colony ship which brought that particular group, and the distance between them was to make sure they didn't accidentally land on top of each other.

You could say they have multiple ships so as to to increase the possibility of the embryos arriving, so one ship failing doesn't doom the whole colony, and that smaller ships are easier to build and outfit than a single massive ship.

You now have tech which is as advanced as you want it to be, since it came in the ships that brought the civ to the new world, but conditions as sparse and crude outside those settlements as it can get. You can even have differing levels of technology between settlements as some ships may have been built later, or there may be a single large ship for the colony capital and multiple smaller ships for other settlements. It's an incredibly versatile but simple and relatively realistic concept which is probably why you'll find it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

**Cultural/Survival reasons**

Why did the embryo ship set out in the first place? Maybe it was a last ditch effort by the original planet in the face of an imminent or likely apocalypse.

It is plausible that such an apocalypse could have been contributed to by the interconnectedness of the original planet. Maybe a killer virus was rapidly spread by global travel networks or an emergent disaster could not be combated by a rigid, homogenised society.

Starting out on a new planet the AIs and training resources available to the new colonists could place a heavy stress on diversity and local communities. The lack of transport would thus be a conscious choice to maintain different outlooks and resources.

Comment: Earth was in its last throes. It could no longer sustain life. It was a dead, dry ball.

Answer (score 0):

The A.I. androids used only flying levitating transport vehicles. Also, they were extremely maneuverable, so they could be parked/stored almost anywhere they fitted in and could move from place A to place B directly by flying, even if they eventually needed to fly through tortuous indoors paths, or over oceans, or over mountains, or over forests, or through anywere they could, which they always easily and flawlessly did.

This way, every settlement is just a pile of interconnected rooms and halls. There was no roads, streets, airports, landing spots or even garages because those are structures that were completely unneeded.

However, those vehicles were entirely controlled by the androids' A.I. The reason is because this way there was no need for human drivers and hence no room for human failure. Also, the A.I. could drive them much better than any human could and also efficiently control the traffic.

But, after shutting down the androids, the humans have no way to control those vehicles anymore, and now, they just remains around permanently parked being silent and useless.